# git clone from private repo using ssh key and ansible script giving error

Tags: ssh, automation, repository, ansible

Following is my ansible playbook file for ssh & cloning repo.

```
- name: Creates .ssh directory for root
  sudo: yes
  file: path=/root/.ssh state=directory

- name: Configure SSH public key & permissions                                                   
  copy: src=id_rsa dest=/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub mode=0644 owner=root group=root

- name: Configure SSH private key & permissions                                  
  copy: src=id_rsa dest=/root/.ssh/id_rsa mode=0600 owner=root group=root

- name: Configure SSH config                                              
  copy: src=config dest=/root/.ssh/config  

- name: Application installation
  git: repo={{ repo_name }} 
       dest={{ project_path }} 
       version={{ deployment_version }}
       recursive=yes
       track_submodules=yes
       accept_hostkey=yes
       clone=yes
       key_file=/root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

While run this script from sudo user, i'm getting following errors. Please help me to look at where i done the mistake.

> fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/git
>   clone     --origin origin '' /var/www/html/myapp", "failed": true,
>   "msg": "Cloning into '/var/www/html/myapp'...\nkey_load_public:
>   invalid format\r\nkey_load_public: invalid format\r\nPermission denied
>   (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access
>   rights\nand the repository exists.", "rc": 128, "stderr": "Cloning
>   into '/var/www/html/myapp'...\nkey_load_public: invalid
>   format\r\nkey_load_public: invalid format\r\nPermission denied
>   (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access
>   rights\nand the repository exists.\n", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines":
>   []}

Comment: "*i'm getting following errors*" - you forgot to include the errors.

Comment: sorry for it, included now

Comment: Did you apply the advice from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41960631/2947502)?

Comment: yes, its giving extra error message : "Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '104.192.143.2' to the list of known hosts"

Comment: It's not an error. Please edit your question so that readers can understand what is the current state.

Comment: @sasi did you manage to resolve this issue eventually?

Answer (score 0):

You are copying the same key for public and private part.I think you need to check that:

```
- name: Configure SSH public key & permissions
  sudo: yes                                                  
  copy: src=id_rsa.pub dest=/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub mode=0644 owner=root group=root
```

- name: Application installation
  sudo: yes
  git: repo={{ repo_name }} 
     dest={{ project_path }} 
     version={{ deployment_version }}
     recursive=yes
     track_submodules=yes
     accept_hostkey=yes
     clone=yes

Comment: manual deployment its working good. I used following reference url to deploy - https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

Comment: @sasi under which user you are manually running the clone command. Please update the question with this info